# Cannot read shared memory written by one child from the other

Tags: ipc, shared-memory

My code below creates two children. One child writes to the shared memory and the other tries to read it. However when I see the output printed after reading, it reads a null string instead of "Hello".

I was able to write from a parent and read from a child. But when I try to write from a child and read from the other, I couldn't.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h>

void spawn_children(int num_child_processes) {
    int pid=0;
    int i=0;

    for(i = 0; i < num_child_processes; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error\n");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("[PID:%0d] Parent=%0d\n",(int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
            if(i==0) {
                // ftok to generate unique key 
                key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65); 

                // shmget returns an identifier in shmid 
                int shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT); 

                // shmat to attach to shared memory 
                char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 

                str = "Hello";
                printf("Data written in memory: %s\n",str); 

                //detach from shared memory  
                shmdt(str);
            }
            else {
                // ftok to generate unique key 
                key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65); 

                // shmget returns an identifier in shmid 
                int shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT); 

                // shmat to attach to shared memory 
                char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 

                printf("Data read from memory: %s\n",str); 

                //detach from shared memory  
                shmdt(str);

                // destroy the shared memory 
                shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL); 
            }
            exit(0);
        } else  {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
        printf("Main process id= %0d, Parent PID = %0d\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());

        spawn_children(2);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first thought it was an ordering issue where the read was occurring before the write which still might be occurring. Until I saw that you were attempting to copy a string via assignment.

The issue is that you never actually write into the shared memory because:

```
str = "Hello";
```

Doesn't copy the string constant `"Hello"` into the memory referred to by `str` but rather makes `str` point to the string constant. To fix this you should use a means of string copying. I like `snprintf`.

I thought I should include an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char * str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  /* writes Hello into the allocated buffer */
  snprintf(str, 100, "%s", "Hello");
  printf("%s %p\n", str, str);
  free(str); 
  str = NULL;
  /* changes pointer to refer to literal constant */
  str = "Hello";
  printf("%s %p\n", str, str);
}
```